# What form is not yet in the example below?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

> **Girl**: "Can I eat it now?"
>
> **Mom**: "Not yet"

Is it even correct to use ***not yet*** this way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a common expression. "Not yet" in answer to a question means that the answer at the current moment is "no", but the implication is that later on, at some (unspecified) time in the future, the answer will become "yes".